# How can I split" Feb 9 2022, 9:55 PM" in excel by a formula?

Tags: excel-formula

The Format is Date

=INT() didn't work

Comment: Just because you format it as a date does not make it so.  This is probably a date stored as text not a true date which if you changed to general format would change to a number.  You will need to parse the string and put the "date" in a format that excel can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you format it as a date does not make it so. This is probably a date stored as text not a true date which if you changed to general format would change to a number. You will need to parse the string and put the "date" in a format that excel can understand then take the INT to get just the date:

```
=INT(--REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","{{{",2)),0,","))
```

One note, this method only works if the month value like `Feb` is in the local language.  If one has a local language of Portuguese `Feb` is not the correct abbreviation, and as such will fail.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin date functions Day() Month() Year() Hour() Minute().